# how can I record my acoustic guitar on Linux using Ardour and Rakarrak?

Tags: compatibility, ardour

I'm running Linux, and was recommended to use Ardour and Rakarrak for recording, but I haven't even gotten Jackd to recognize my guitar. Currently, the guitar is connected with a 1/4" to 1/8" cable directly from the pre-amp pickup in the guitar to the Mic In on my computer. Help!

Answer (score 3):

Can you record with `jack` using a generic computer mic plugged into the mic in port?  Your answer will let us know whether it is a problem with the configuration of `jack` or a hardware problem (perhaps your guitar's preamp isn't boosting the signal enough--or, more likely, is out of battery).

In any case, you probably won't get very good quality with this method, the analog to digital converters for the mic in line on most soundcards are pretty terrible--only intended for voice really.  You would have better luck using a linux friendly USB audio device.  I own a M-audio Fast Track Pro, and am am fairly happy with it, athough it does require a little bit of configuring to unlock it's full capabilities.